# Sending Emails from Excel VBA - Names Not Recognized

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am using the below code to send an email from excel using outlook:

```
Private Sub SendEmail()

  Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  newmsg.Recipients.Add ("name@domain.com; name2@domain.com; name3@domain.com")

  newmsg.Subject = "Test Mail"

  newmsg.Body = "This is a test email."

  'newmsg.Display

  newmsg.Send

End Sub
```

The code works just fine, however I get the below error from Outlook when trying to send the email:

[ErrorScreen http://im58.gulfup.com/GRENlB.png](http://im58.gulfup.com/GRENlB.png)

The strange thing is that if I leave the new message open for two or three minutes the names automatically get resolved:

[Working http://im74.gulfup.com/qmOYGQ.png](http://im74.gulfup.com/qmOYGQ.png)

However this doesn't suit me as I don't want the message to be displayed before it's sent. I am looking to have it send as soon as I run the code.

Any suggestions or workarounds will be appreciated.

As a side note: I have tried enabling the "Allow commas as email separators" option in outlook, and then using the commas instead of the semicolons, but I am still facing the same problem.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the working code, as per **Dmitry Streblechenko's** answer:

```
Private Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ("name@domain.com; name2@domain.com; name3@domain.com")
        .Subject = "Test Mail"
        .Body = "This is a test email."
        '.Display
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe `newmsg.Recipients.Add ("name@domain.com; name2@domain.com; name3@domain.com")` is the problem.  It is a long time since I did this but I recall the names must be added separately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple names to Recipients.Add - you get a single recipient with the name of "name@domain.com; name2@domain.com; name3@domain.com". Either call Recipients.Add 3 times once for each recipient or set the To property - it will parse multiple names.

Comment: Perfect! I have changed the `newmsg.Recipients.Add` and used the `To` property, totally solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Me too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You should add a call to `ResolveAll` to explicitely resolve all recipients. 
Otherwise, resolution is done automatically after a short waiting period.

**Example:**

```
Sub CheckRecipients()      
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)      
 Set myRecipients = myItem.Recipients 

 myRecipients.Add("Aaron Con")      
 myRecipients.Add("Nate Sun")      
 myRecipients.Add("Dan Wilson") 

 If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then      
     For Each myRecipient In myRecipients      
        If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then      
           MsgBox myRecipient.Name      
        End If      
     Next      
 End If      
End Sub
```

Code copied from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867165%28v=office.15%29.aspx).